# htacess redirect is not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using `create-react-app` together with `react-router`. How can I make any of the following variations (I don't think I missed any):

- www.example.com
- example.com
- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com

redirect to:

https://example.com (notice the https secured, and no www.)

I created an .htaccess file with the following code:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  IndexIgnore */*
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) /

</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "sw\.js$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

When I add that, the routes get directed to secured https, but the www is there when I type it in the url. How can I have the browser always redirect to not have www.?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77278/force-https-and-no-www-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

The rediretion to another host should work better like that, note the hard wired target host name:

```
RewriteEngone on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

Place those rules before any internal rewriting rules (your example shows a general rewriting to ?`/`).

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).